# Does Spark filtering reload the data?

Tags: java, groovy, apache-spark

This is the main body of my really simple Spark job...

```
def hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(config, TableInputFormat.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class)
println "${hBaseRDD.count()} records counted"
def filteredRDD = hBaseRDD.filter({ scala.Tuple2 result ->
    def val = result._2.getValue(family, qualifier)
    val ? new String(val) == 'twitter' : false
} as Function<Result, Boolean>)
println "${filteredRDD.count()} counted from twitter."
println "Done!"
```

I noticed in the spark-submit output, that it appeared to go to HBase twice. The first time was when it called count on `hBaseRDD` and the second was when it called filter to create `filteredRDD`. Is there a way to get it to cache the results of the `newAPIHadoopRDD` call in hBaseRDD so that filter works on an in-memory only copy of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hbaseRDD.cache()` before counting will do the trick.

The docs cover the options in detail: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence